# Método para leer línea por línea de un archivo de texto

Tags: java

Hola tengo un método para leer un txt y otro que me cuenta la cantidad de lineas de este. quisiera hacer otro método para recorrerlo linea por linea

```
public void LeerArchivo(String _Nombre) {
    try {
        BufferedReader _fd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(_Nombre));
        this.File = _fd;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void ContarLineas() {
    try{
        String Linea = this.File.readLine();
        while (Linea != null){
            System.out.println(Linea);
            Linea = this.File.readLine();
            NroLineas++;
        }
        System.out.println("Este archivo tiene " + NroLineas + " lineas ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Saludos Yisela. En realidad **ya lo estás haciendo**, fíjate en el método `ContarLineas`, justo ese `while` se utiliza para leer el archivo, (cabe mencionar que al aplicar un `System.out.println(Linea);` lo imprimes en pantalla...

Comment: como haria entonces .... lo pondria dentro de un bucle ????

Comment: por que necesito recorrer linea x linea ... por que tengo otro metodo donde tengo k ver si la linea "n" cumple o no una dicha condicion

Comment: Sí, básicamente es lo mismo, solo que ya no ocupas "contar líneas" sino "leer líneas". Tu variable `Linea` es la que tiene el texto que necesitas para hacer la comprobación que necesites.

Comment: entonces ... lo mas fácil seria .... asignarlo en un array linea x linea ???  porfa .. puedes hacerme un ejemplo ??

Comment: @yiselaalataespinoza lee [ask] y completa el [tour]. Stack Overflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas y no un foro. Familiarízate con nuestro funcionamiento y lo que se espera de las publicaciones y los usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

La clase `BufferedReader` ofrece el método `lines()` que es útil en tu caso. Ya que al haber leído una vez las líneas del archivo (para contarlas), si quieres volver a leerlas para saber su contenido, tendrías que volver a cargar el `BufferedReader` con tu archivo, puesto que ya habrá llegado al final de documento.

Podrías realizar algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
public class MiClase {

    Object[] lineas; // arreglo que almacenará las líneas de tu archivo

    public void contarLineas() {
        System.out.println("Este archivo tiene " + lineas.length + " lineas");
    }

    public void cargarArchivo(String archivo) {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            lineas = br.lines().toArray(); // inicializa el arreglo con las líneas de tu archivo

            // Se cierran los lectores puesto que ya no se necesitarán
            br.close();
            fr.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void leerArchivo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lineas.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(lineas[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MiClase me = new MiClase();
        me.cargarArchivo("aquí va la ruta de tu archivo");
        me.contarLineas();
        me.leerArchivo();
    }
}
```

Básicamente necesitarías los métodos `contarLineas`, `cargarArchivo` y `leerArchivo`, lo demás es a modo de ejemplo.

En el caso del método `leerArchivo`, el `for` te permitirá saber la línea en la que estás (el contador `i` es el número de línea).

Comment: Muchas gracias ..... Me salvaste @C.Rodriguez